# I am getting an error while inserting rows using mysql npm library

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert many rows using for loop for insertingrows via mysql library. However I am getting error. I checked and the columns match but somehow i still get this error

The row insertion is working for every element except this one for no apparent reason

```
{ Error: ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Pool.query (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
    at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Pool.query (internal/util.js:273:12)
    at Converter.csv.fromStream.on (/home/abhian/flowace/decrypt-database/processUploadTable.js:123:30)
    at Converter.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Converter.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at Converter.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:491:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:957:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:938:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',
  errno: 1136,
  sqlMessage: 'Column count doesn\'t match value count at row 1',
  sqlState: '21S01',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'insert into `timesheet` (`id`,`type`,`app_id`,`app_name`,`app_title`,`app_path`,`timestamp_start`,`timestamp_end`,`duration`,`user_id`,`matter_id`,`updated_by_user_id`,`timestamp_create`,`source`,`user_rate`,`cost`,`description`,`location_name`,`conflict`,`suggestion`) Values (\'2086233\', \'PLUGIN\', \'5232\', \'oMgqTrYiZVQp.exe\', \'qZXhgWtnwvQq\', \'c:/nXnXlwXp/uenlbnnx\', \'2016-05-06T18:21:29.000Z\', \'2016-05-18 19:29:50.000\', \'1021101\', \'4\', \'1\', \'-1\', \'2019-06-15T01:13:34.000Z\', NULL, \'15000\', \'4254.5875\', NULL, NULL, \'0\', NULL)' }
```

Comment: hi,

typically this message means, you have more columns than rows, when i remember right. I've checked the rows and counted the values, it seems to be right. Did you check the row names for typos?

You set any constraints? Maybe you like to insert a string but its integer . Or you definded, it shouldnt be null and you set null

Comment: Hi. I figured it out, there was some issue in trigger of my table. it would have been great if mysql let us know  where the error originates

Comment: glad to hear that :) may i ask, what exactly was the problem with the trigger? the error maybe isnt that bad